# Solve equation for alpha

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$E_1 = Ch_1^\alpha$

How can I solve for the exponent alpha?

Is it just $\frac{\frac{E_1}{C}}{ln(\alpha)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get

$$h_1^\alpha = \frac{E_1}{C}$$

Tking the log, you get

$$\alpha \ln(h_1) = \ln \frac{E_1}{C}$$

You can easily get $\alpha$ from here. Your answer is almost right, unfortunately, almost right also means wrong ;)

Comment: Thanks :D so I did have it right.

Comment: Why is RHS not $\log \frac{E_1}{C}$?

Comment: Fixed, I knew I should go to sleep instead of answering questions :)